# email access using facebook authentication rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to access the user email through facebook authentication.
my code in authentication controller

def facebook

```
     omni= request.env["omniauth.auth"]
authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'],omni['uid'])
    if authentication
        flash[:notice]="Logged in successfully"
        sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
    elsif current_user
        token=omni['credentials'].token
        token_secret=omni['credentials'].secret

        current_user.authentications.create!(:provider=>omni['provider'],:uid=>omni['uid'],:token=>token,:token_secret=>token_secret)
        flash[:notice]="Authentication successful."
        sign_in_and_redirect current_user
    else
        user=User.new
    #   user.email=omni['extra']['raw_info'].email
        user.apply_omniauth(omni)
        if user.save
            flash[:notice]="Logged in."
            sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)
        else
            session[:omniauth]=omni.except('extra')
            redirect_to new_user_registration_path
        end 
    end
end
```

devise.rb

config.omniauth :facebook, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx851','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd47aae3', {:scope => ' email,publish_stream,offline_access' ,:display => 'popup'}

in user model

```
def apply_omniauth(omni)
  authentications.build(:provider => omni['provider'],
  :uid=>omni['uid'],
  :token=>omni['credentials'].token,
  :token_secret=>omni['credentials'].secret,
  )

  x=omni["info"]["name"].split                              # split the full name into first and last name                                  
  self.first_name=x[0]
  self.last_name=x[1]
  self.profile_name=omni['info']['nickname']
```

end

Is their something in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Last, I remember, `email` can be found at `omni.info.email`.
Also, I advice you to use `.` notation here, instead of hash.

Comment: :when I do raise request.env["omniauth.auth"] , i haven't found the email field.

Comment: but you asked for that permission in the `scope`. So, FB must be returning that if user approved that.